# The hunt for the missing dialog value ^^

Tags: sapui5

Helloooo experts,

I have a dialog which I use both for creating and updating entries. Everything works fine, except a tiny (but still annoying) bit.

When I call the dialog for an existing entry, everything is smooth. Fields appear normally and update works alright.

When I call the dialog to create a new entry, I get a set of blank fields, I fill them all, press save and works OK. Where is the problem? One of these fields should have already a value since I have already assign a value with the oModel.createEntry method. I debug the app the properties for the entry look alright, everything seems alright (if not blind) but the value doesn't come with the field - rings any bells?

Code (quite short) attached below, field in doubt: iAgrId.

Thanks!

Greg

[Debugger snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jwMC.jpg)

```
        onActionAdd: function() {

            var oModel = this.getView().getModel();

            //oModel.createEntry("/Agreement_ActionsSet");
            var oActionEditDialog = new Dialog({title: "Create Action"});

            this.createActionFormData(oActionEditDialog, oModel);

            //get Agreement ID
            var sAgreement = this.getView().getBindingContext().toString().slice(16,26);
            var oNewObject = "{\"AgrId\": \"" + sAgreement + "\"}";
            oNewObject = JSON.parse(oNewObject);
            this.getView().addDependent(oActionEditDialog);
            var oEntry = oModel.createEntry("/Agreement_ActionsSet", oNewObject);
            oActionEditDialog.setBindingContext(oEntry);
            //oActionEditDialog.bindElement(oEntry);

            oActionEditDialog.open();
        },
        onActionEdit: function(oSourceEvent) {

            var oModel = this.getView().getModel();

            var oActionEditDialog = new Dialog({title: "Edit Action Details"});

            this.createActionFormData(oActionEditDialog, oModel);

            //to get access to the global model
            var sPath = oSourceEvent.getSource().getParent().getBindingContext().toString();
            this.getView().addDependent(oActionEditDialog);
            oActionEditDialog.bindElement(sPath);

            oActionEditDialog.open();
        },
        // populate form fields
        createActionFormData: function(oActionEditDialog, oModel) {

            var oActionTypeItemTemplate = new sap.ui.core.ListItem({ key:"{f4>AgrActtypeid}", text:"{f4>AgrActtypeid}", additionalText:"{f4>AgrActtypetxt}"});
            var oActionStatusItemTemplate = new sap.ui.core.ListItem({ key:"{f4>AgrStatid}", text:"{f4>AgrStatid}", additionalText:"{f4>AgrStattxt}"});
            var oActionAgentItemTemplate = new sap.ui.core.ListItem({ key:"{f4>AgrAgentid}", text:"{f4>AgrAgentid}", additionalText:"{f4>AgrAgenttxt}"});

            var sAgrId = new sap.m.Label({text: "{i18n>actionAgrId}"});
            var iAgrId = new sap.m.Input({value: "{AgrId}"});               
            var sAgrActionid = new sap.m.Label({text: "{i18n>actionLineItemTableIDColumn}"});
            var iAgrActionid = new sap.m.Input({value: "{AgrActionid}", enabled: false}); 
            var sCreatedBy = new sap.m.Label({text: "{i18n>actionCreatedBy}"});
            var iCreatedBy = new sap.m.Input({value: "{CreatedBy}"});
            var sCreatedOn = new sap.m.Label({text: "{i18n>actionCreatedOn}"});
            var iCreatedOn = new sap.m.DatePicker({value: "{ path: 'CreatedOn', type:'sap.ui.model.type.Date', formatOptions: { style: 'medium', strictParsing: true} }"});
            var sActionComment = new sap.m.Label({text: "{i18n>actionComment}"});
            var iActionComment = new sap.m.Input({value: "{ActionComment}"});
            var sAgrActionDate = new sap.m.Label({text: "{i18n>actionActionDate}"});
            var iAgrActionDate = new sap.m.DatePicker({value: "{ path: 'AgrActionDate', type:'sap.ui.model.type.Date', formatOptions: { style: 'medium', strictParsing: true} }"});
            var sAgrChaseDate = new sap.m.Label({text: "{i18n>actionChaseDate}"});
            var iAgrChaseDate = new sap.m.DatePicker({value: "{ path: 'AgrChaseDate', type:'sap.ui.model.type.Date', formatOptions: { style: 'medium', strictParsing: true} }"});
            var sAgrActtypeid = new sap.m.Label({text: "{i18n>actionActionType}"});
            var iAgrActtypeid = new sap.m.ComboBox({ 
                                //id: "cbRoleType", 
                                selectedKey: "{AgrActtypeid}",
                                //selectedItemId: "{AgrRoletptxt}",
                                showSecondaryValues :  true,
                                items: {
                                    path: "f4>/Action_TypesSet",
                                    template: oActionTypeItemTemplate,
                                    templateShareable: "false"}
                    }).bindProperty("value", "AgrActtypeid");
            var sAgrStatidFrom = new sap.m.Label({text: "{i18n>actionStatusFrom}"});
            var iAgrStatidFrom = new sap.m.ComboBox({ 
                                //id: "cbRoleType", 
                                selectedKey: "{AgrStatidFrom}",
                                //selectedItemId: "{AgrRoletptxt}",
                                showSecondaryValues :  true,
                                items: {
                                    path: "f4>/Agreement_StatusesSet",
                                    template: oActionStatusItemTemplate,
                                    templateShareable: "false"}
                    }).bindProperty("value", "AgrStatidFrom");  
            var sAgrStatidTo = new sap.m.Label({text: "{i18n>actionStatusTo}"});
            var iAgrStatidTo = new sap.m.ComboBox({ 
                                //id: "cbRoleType", 
                                selectedKey: "{AgrStatidTo}",
                                //selectedItemId: "{AgrRoletptxt}",
                                showSecondaryValues :  true,
                                items: {
                                    path: "f4>/Agreement_StatusesSet",
                                    template: oActionStatusItemTemplate,
                                    templateShareable: "false"}
                    }).bindProperty("value", "AgrStatidTo");                            
            var sAgrAgentidFrom = new sap.m.Label({text: "{i18n>actionAgentFrom}"});
            var iAgrAgentidFrom = new sap.m.ComboBox({ 
                                //id: "cbRoleType", 
                                selectedKey: "{AgrAgentidFrom}",
                                //selectedItemId: "{AgrRoletptxt}",
                                showSecondaryValues :  true,
                                items: {
                                    path: "f4>/Agreement_AgentsSet",
                                    template: oActionAgentItemTemplate,
                                    templateShareable: "false"}
                    }).bindProperty("value", "AgrAgentidFrom");
            var sAgrAgentidTo = new sap.m.Label({text: "{i18n>actionAgentTo}"});
            var iAgrAgentidTo = new sap.m.ComboBox({ 
                                //id: "cbRoleType", 
                                selectedKey: "{AgrAgentidTo}",
                                //selectedItemId: "{AgrRoletptxt}",
                                showSecondaryValues :  true,
                                items: {
                                    path: "f4>/Agreement_AgentsSet",
                                    template: oActionAgentItemTemplate,
                                    templateShareable: "false"}
                    }).bindProperty("value", "AgrAgentidTo");                       

            var oSaveButton = new sap.ui.commons.Button({
                        text: "Save",
                        press: function (oEvent) {
                            oModel.submitChanges({
                                success: function(oData, sResponse) {
                                },
                                error: function(oError) {
                                    jQuery.sap.log.error("oData Failure", oError);
                                }
                            });                                 
                            oEvent.getSource().getParent().close();
                        }
            });
            var oCancelButton = new sap.ui.commons.Button({
                        text: "Cancel",
                        press: function (oEvent) {
                            oModel.resetChanges();
                            oEvent.getSource().getParent().close();
                        }
            });

            oActionEditDialog.addContent(sAgrId);
            oActionEditDialog.addContent(iAgrId);               
            oActionEditDialog.addContent(sAgrActionid);
            oActionEditDialog.addContent(iAgrActionid);
            oActionEditDialog.addContent(sCreatedBy);
            oActionEditDialog.addContent(iCreatedBy);   
            oActionEditDialog.addContent(sCreatedOn);
            oActionEditDialog.addContent(iCreatedOn);               
            oActionEditDialog.addContent(sActionComment);
            oActionEditDialog.addContent(iActionComment);
            oActionEditDialog.addContent(sAgrActionDate);
            oActionEditDialog.addContent(iAgrActionDate);   
            oActionEditDialog.addContent(sAgrChaseDate);
            oActionEditDialog.addContent(iAgrChaseDate);                
            oActionEditDialog.addContent(sAgrActtypeid);
            oActionEditDialog.addContent(iAgrActtypeid);
            oActionEditDialog.addContent(sAgrStatidFrom);
            oActionEditDialog.addContent(iAgrStatidFrom);
            oActionEditDialog.addContent(sAgrStatidTo);
            oActionEditDialog.addContent(iAgrStatidTo);
            oActionEditDialog.addContent(sAgrAgentidFrom);
            oActionEditDialog.addContent(iAgrAgentidFrom);
            oActionEditDialog.addContent(sAgrAgentidTo);
            oActionEditDialog.addContent(iAgrAgentidTo);

            oActionEditDialog.addContent(oSaveButton);
            oActionEditDialog.addContent(oCancelButton);
        },
```

Comment: Can you share an image of what do you get and where do you expect fix in it ?

Comment: I was getting a blank field, solution found, was about incorrect declaration of parameters in createEntry method, thanks for taking the time to deal with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in the parameter definition in the createEntry method, correct statement below:

*var oEntry = oModel.createEntry("/Agreement_ActionsSet", {properties:oNewObject});*